# No session token (JWT) or API Key detected in request Error in PHP

Tags: php, curl, dreamfactory

I am using the `curl` for get the `JSON` data from `DreamFactory` url.
But I a getting the error.

> No session token (JWT) or API Key detected in request. Please send in
>   X-DreamFactory-Session-Token and/or X-Dreamfactory-API-Key request
>   header. You can also use URL query parameters session_token and/or
>   api_key.

**My php code**

```
<?php
header("X-DreamFactory-API-Key:TestKey"); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://dev.spotya.online:82/api/v2/user/register/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"email=ramalingam.p@pickzy.com&first_name=Ramalingam&last_name=Perumal&display_name=Ramalingam&new_password=123456&phone=1234567890");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($server_output);
?>
```

Please advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this. There is no need to initiate headers at your end, You have to send header which contains your `API-Key`

By adding these few lines in your code

```
$headers=array(
            "X-DreamFactory-API-Key: TestKey" //your api-key
        );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);// adding headers with curl-request
```

**Complete PHP code:**

```
<?php
$headers=array(
            "X-DreamFactory-API-Key: TestKey" 
        ); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://dev.spotya.online:82/api/v2/user/register/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"email=ramalingam.p@pickzy.com&first_name=Ramalingam&last_name=Perumal&display_name=Ramalingam&new_password=123456&phone=1234567890");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($server_output);
?>
```

Comment: "error":{"code":403,"context":null,"message":"Open Registration is not enabled."

Comment: @RamaLingam So the error which you stated above has been fixed, for this particular you have to look into apidocs of `dev.spotya.online`

Comment: It's working fine. After change the config `Open Registration is enabled.`